# How to detect if app is in background but screen is on/app is in the foreground but screen is off?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to monitor whether the app is in the background or not, but while also tracking whether the screen is on or off, and there is no way to know if the screen is on/off. I need to know be able to tell these two combinations:

1. Screen is ON but app is in BACKGROUND
2. Screen is OFF but app is in FOREGROUND

I tried using `WidgetsBindingObserver`. The problem is this tells me the app is in the background when the screen goes off.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/screen_state), it looks helpful !